# Level curve and PDE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification, partial-differential-equations, fluid-dynamics, diffeomorphism

Suppose you have the following PDE sistem:
$$u\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+v\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=\nu \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}$$ $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}=0$$
If we set $\overline{x}=ax$ and $\overline{y}=by$, performing substitutions we notice that for $a=b^2$ and $\overline{v}=bv$ we obtein the original PDE sistem. In particular we notice that $u(b^2x,by)=u(x,y)$ $\forall b>0$. So the question is: how can we proof that $u$ is costant on the curve of equation: $$Y=\frac{y}{\sqrt{x}}\sqrt{X}$$
?
Thank you for the answers.

Comment: Just what is $X$?

Comment: Do you know anything about [similarity solutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similarity_solution)?

Comment: @CheeHan actually I don’t know. I understood everything since this last equation but the author provide this formula without any proof

Comment: @Mattos yes I know but, how can I apply to obtain the equation for Y?

Comment: Let the scaling be $u(x,y) = U(b^{2}X, bY)$. Then a combination of variables that remains unchanged by the transformation is $$\frac{x}{y^{2}} = \frac{b^{2} X}{b^{2} Y^{2}} = \frac{X}{Y^{2}} \implies Y = y \sqrt{\frac{X}{x}}$$ So look for a solution of the form $u = f(x/y^{2})$.

Comment: @Mattos  thank you so much, your comment was so useful and I understood this change of variable